# Apply Equalizer on Orbit slider in Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit, equalizer

I am trying to get all of the slides in my orbit slider to be the height of the largest slide.

Here is my markup:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.orbit-container').equalize('outerHeight');
});
```

```html
<div class="orbit" data-orbit="" role="region" data-auto-play="false" data-resize="7sdsk0-orbit" id="7sdsk0-orbit" data-t="3k1v70-t"><button class="orbit-previous" tabindex="0"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>◀︎</button><button class="orbit-next" tabindex="0"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>▶︎</button><div class="orbit-wrapper">
<ul class="orbit-container" data-options="bullets: true; autoPlay:false;" data-auto-play="false" data-equalizer="" data-equalize-on-stack="true" data-equalize-by-row="true" data-resize="lo2q16-eq" data-mutate="k2tsn5-eq" data-t="fgxh6n-t" tabindex="0" style="height: 0px;" data-events="mutate">

  <li data-equalizer-watch class="orbit-slide" data-slide="0">
    <div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h1>Arthritis. Give Before it takes.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisi elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, nostrud</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>    
      </div>
      <div class="inner-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
      <img alt="" class="orbit-image desktop" src="/AS/media/AS/Homepage%20Billboards/billboard-tweaked.jpg?ext=.jpg">
      <img alt="" class="orbit-image mobile" src="/AS/media/AS/Homepage%20Billboards/mobile-cropped.jpg?ext=.jpg">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-equalizer-watch class="orbit-slide is-active" data-slide="1" aria-live="polite">
    <div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisi elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, nostrud</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>  
      </div>
      <div class="inner-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
      <img alt="" class="orbit-image desktop" src="/AS/media/AS/Homepage%20Billboards/billboard-tweaked.jpg?ext=.jpg">
      <img alt="" class="orbit-image mobile" src="/AS/media/AS/Test%20Images/rough-mobile.jpg?ext=.jpg">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

On each li, an inline style is being applied of height="auto", so the slides are different heights. Even if I call that function after the window has loaded, it has the same effect.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be the type of display property on the li elements causing it (i.e. block vs inline-block vs inline). Try changing those and seeing if it has an effect.

Comment: @aibrean it does not make a different